# a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "void(*)(struct *Queue, int)

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I've the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int *arr;
    int maxSize, curSize;
    int first, last;
    int(*isEmptyFunc)(Queue);
    int(*isFullFunc)(Queue);
    void(*EnqueueFunc)(struct Queue*, int);
    void(*DequeueFunc)(struct Queue*);
    int(*TopFunc)(Queue);
} Queue;
```

And a create queue function that returns a pointer to a new queue:

```
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    isNull(arr);
    Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    isNull(q);
```

When I try to assign values to the function pointers, I do: 
(It all happen in the CreateQueue function)

```
q->isEmptyFunc = isEmpty(*q);
q->isFullFunc = isFull(*q);
q->TopFunc = Top(*q);
q->DequeueFunc = Dequeue(q);
```

The actual functions are declared in a header file I included in the top of the .c file, and implemented just below the CreateQueue func.
The first three assignments seem to be fine, but for the fourth the compiler screams:

```
IntelliSense: a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "void (*)(struct Queue *)"
```

The Dequeue function implementation is:

```
void Dequeue(Queue *q) {
    if (q->isEmptyFunc()) return;
    q->first = (q->first + 1) % (q->maxSize);
    q->curSize--;
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `Dequeue` is a *function (pointer)*, `Dequeue(q)` is the *result of a function call*.  These are not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem here is, `isEmptyFunc`, `isFullFunc`, `EnqueueFunc` and `DequeueFunc`, all are **function pointers**. You're trying to put a return value of a function call, (here, which is not a *function pointer*, we can assume). That is completely wrong. It is **not** fine and you should not be doing that.

Now, if we see, in your case

> *The first three assignments seem to be fine,*

The compiler does not complain here, because all the three function calls return some value (possibly `int`?) and that is *implicitly* converted to the *function pointer* type, however, the behavior is not defined. You **must not** do that.

> *but for the fourth the compiler screams:*

in that case, the `Dequeue()` function return type is `void`, which cannot be used as a *value*. So, the compiler is (*thankfully*) complaining.

**TL;DR** you need to change *all* those above statements.